# What is the interpretation of these hydrogen probability density diagrams?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, hydrogen, orbitals

[image]

In the diagram above, what is the interpretation of all of the individual renders? Does the hydrogen atom continuously change between these states? For example, will $(n, l, m_l)$ become $(2, 0, 0)$ at one point in time, and then later spontaneously change to $(2, 1, 1)$ depending on which of the two is most probable? Sorry if this question isn't phrased too well, I'm new to this realm of physics.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the images shown is a slice of the wavefunction for the hydrogen-like atomic orbitals. The square of each function gives the probability density for finding an electron at a particular region in space. Nodes between parts of the orbitals are regions of 0 probability. Note that this does not mean that the electron is a ball that is rolling around “inside” of this region of space. The electron is a wave and a particle simultaneously and smears out over space in a way that matches the state it is in. The different colors of the wavefunction itself (not shown in this particular image) correspond to regions of differing phase. You might think of this like the peaks and troughs of a normal wave you might see in the ocean or in a vibrating string. Until you start worrying about things like inter nuclear bonds the phase doesn’t matter a ton besides telling you what orbital you are looking at, but the constructive or destructive overlap of the shaded regions matters a lot when considering chemical bonding.

In general, the easiest reason you might see a transition occur is if there is a lower energy state that is unoccupied. One of the standard rules of physics is that nature wishes to be in the lowest energy state it can be in, at least up to degeneracies. But, in your example, there would be little reason for the atom to spontaneously pick up or lose angular momentum and change its state. This could be mediated by some sort of process like absorbing and then re-emitting a photon, but it wouldn’t be likely to happen on its own.

Comment: It's not a projection, it's a cross section.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. Late night brain is not always the most precise.

Answer (score 1):

In quantum mechanics, wave functions evolve in time via the *Hamiltonian* operator (this evolution is also known as the *Schrodinger equation*). The eigenvectors of this operator have a special meaning - they are wave functions that have a specific energy level that doesn't change in time (this energy is the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector).

Each of the pictures you showed one of these energy **eigenfunctions**. Each picture is a stable setup for the Hydrogen's single electron moving around the nucleus (a proton), with the color corresponding the the probability finding the electron at different places. If the electron doesn't lose or gain energy, if you start with one of these eigenfunction states, you will remain at the same state. The electron may change to a different state with different energy by emitting or absorbing a photon.